# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Entry'

Tags: python, tkinter

Я новичок в языке Python и пытаюсь освоить язык. Написал программу с помощью библиотеки tkinter, которая подсчитывает площадь прямоугольника. Но при нажатии кнопки "Площадь" у меня вылезает ошибка. Я уже 2 день не могу разобраться. Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror, showwarning, showinfo

root=Tk()

#функция для подсчёта площади
def ploshad ():
    a=int(entry)*int(entry1)
    showinfo(title="Площадь", message=a)

#настройка окна 
root.title("Калькулятор площади")
root.geometry("300x345")
root.resizable(False, False)
root["bg"]="#2ea8d2"

#площадь прямоугольника
frame=ttk.Frame(borderwidth=3, relief=SOLID, padding=[8, 10])

lb=Label(frame, text="Площадь", font=("Arial", 14))
lb.pack()

label=Label(frame, text="Введите длину (в см)")
label.pack()

entry=Entry(frame)
entry.pack()

label2=Label(frame, text="Введите ширину (в см)")
label2.pack()

entry1=Entry(frame)
entry1.pack()

btn=Button(frame, text="Площадь", command=ploshad)
btn.pack()

frame.pack(anchor=NW, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь текстовое поле в число преобразовать. Вместо этого нужно получить текст из него, и его уже преобразовывать в число: `int(entry.get())`

Answer (score 2):

Все записано верно, кроме самого значения из `Entry`, при выводе результата всегда добавляем `.get()`, говорящий нам о том, что мы используем то, что вывелось или ввелось пользователем.
То есть, `a=int(entry.get())*int(entry1.get())`

Comment: Помогло, сапсибо!!!

Comment: Нажмите на галочку, чтобы вопрос был снят с нерешённых.